# How to change the icon of Datetimepicker of WPF toolkit?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, wpftoolkit

I want to change the default drop down icon of the DateTimePicker control to a calender icon. How Can i do it?

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 3):

Just modify style of dateTimePicker by right click on it on designer => modify style => create a local copy.

Then you can modify style to insert your own button (name of element is PART_Button)